# SAS: use oberservation

Tags: sas, dde

I have a question on how to use the value from a SAS database in another command. In my case, I have a database with two variables (cell and res). "Cell" contains a reference to a cell in an Excel sheet where the value of "res" should be copied.

So I would like to use the value stored in "cell" in my command linking to the Excel sheet. This code does not work (concatenating with || does not work.)

```
DATA _null_; 
SET test;
FILENAME ExcelTmp DDE "EXCEL|[&myInputTemplate.]&mySheet.!" || cell;
FILE ExcelTmp NOTAB LRECL=7000;
PUT res;
RUN;
```

Error message:

```
ERROR 23-2: Invalid option name ||.

1491! DDE "EXCEL|[&myInputTemplate.]&mySheet.!" || cell;
ERROR: Error in the FILENAME statement.
ERROR 23-2: Invalid option name cell.

1492      FILE ExcelTmp NOTAB LRECL=7000;
ERROR 23-2: Invalid option name NOTAB.
```

If I write

```
FILENAME ExcelTmp DDE "EXCEL|[&myInputTemplate.]&mySheet.!R1C1:R1C1";
```

then the value is written to cell A1 in Excel.

Is there some similar approach that works without invoking a macro?

Thanks for your help!

Christoph

Comment: I would take a look at your `filename` statement, there's something wrong with the syntax.  Are you not missing  `|"` after the word `Excel`?

Comment: It would help if you posted up the actual error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to use values from a dataset as a part of command/statement is `CALL EXECUTE` routine:

```
DATA _null_; 
    SET test;
    call execute("DATA _NULL_;");
    call execute(cats("FILENAME ExcelTmp DDE ""EXCEL|[&myInputTemplate.]&mySheet.!",cell,""";"));
    call execute("FILE ExcelTmp NOTAB LRECL=7000;");
    call execute("PUT '"||res||"';");
    call execute("RUN;");
run;
```

This code generates DATA-steps that stacked up in a buffer and will be executed after the step above is executed. So basically you will generate as many DATA *NULL* steps as you have records in your `test` dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to update multiple cells, and `cell` is in the form RnCn, something like this may work...

You also need to determine the cell range beforehand, e.g. R2C2:R100:C5.

```
%LET RANGE = R2C2:R100C5 ;

DATA _null_; 
SET test;
FILENAME ExcelTmp DDE "EXCEL|[&myInputTemplate.]&mySheet.!&RANGE" ;
FILE ExcelTmp NOTAB LRECL=7000;
put "[select(""" cell """)]" ;
PUT res;
RUN;
```

Comment: Hi,
actually 'cell' is in the range format "RnCn:RnCn". I guess I could easily modify the code such that your approach works. However, I would prefer not to specify a static range at the beginning. That's why I wonder if it is possible to read the range as a single cell for each observation from the database.